# Android - DialogFragment is shown from a Fragment. How to show Toast from Fragment when DialogFragment is dismissed?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

As mentioned in the question..

I have a Fragment from which I create and show a DialogFragment along with setting the targetFragment to this, the current Fragment.

```
DialogFragment_Progress fragmentProgressBar = new DialogFragment_Progress();        
    fragmentProgressBar.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
    fragmentProgressBar.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
```

I do some progress bar updating

```
// Thread that controls progress bar
final Thread progressThread = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {           
        active = true;
        int cumulativetime = 0;

        try
        {
            while (active && cumulativetime < TIME_TOTAL)
            {
                sleep(TIME_INTERVAL);

                if (active)
                {
                    cumulativetime += TIME_INTERVAL;

                    updateProgress(cumulativetime);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
             onContinue();
        }
    }   
};
```

When the progress bad is finished, I try to invoke a method in the target Fragment to show a Toast. The onContinue() code and the method invoked in the targetFragment can be seen below..

```
// Perform final operations
public void onContinue()
{       
    Fragment_Activate_Program_Specific targetFragment = (Fragment_Activate_Program_Specific) getTargetFragment();

    targetFragment.operationComplete();

    dismiss();
}
```

Operation complete..

```
// Operation complete
public void operationComplete()
{       
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Herp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Log.i("Hello: ", "Got here!");
}
```

When I don't try and Toast, all is well, the Log is received. This method has worked for me several times before when no UI is involved.

PROBLEM: When operationComplete() is invoked in the targetFragment(), I get the following exception..

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

Relevant stack trace..

```
05-31 12:21:53.024: W/dalvikvm(28494): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40cc9930)
05-31 12:21:53.034: E/AndroidRuntime(28494): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-14251
05-31 12:21:53.034: E/AndroidRuntime(28494): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
05-31 12:21:53.034: E/AndroidRuntime(28494):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
05-31 12:21:53.034: E/AndroidRuntime(28494):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
05-31 12:21:53.034: E/AndroidRuntime(28494):    at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:324)
05-31 12:21:53.034: E/AndroidRuntime(28494):    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
05-31 12:21:53.034: E/AndroidRuntime(28494):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
05-31 12:21:53.034: E/AndroidRuntime(28494):    at com.mypackage.Activity_Activate_Program.activateOperationComplete(Activity_Activate_Program.java:90)
```

I have tried using the parent Activity as opposed to the calling fragment to host the operationComplete() method but I get the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toasts should be called from the UI Thread.

Try this.

```
public void operationComplete()
{       
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Herp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    Log.i("Hello: ", "Got here!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply override the dismiss method of Dialog fragment this will only call one.

```
@Override
Public void dismiss() {
   Log.e(TAG,"dismiss";
   super.dismiss();
 }
```